# How come when I hover over an ES6 class/class method in VSCode, I don't see the JSDoc comments until I open the file containing the JSDoc comments?

Tags: intellisense, jsdoc, code-documentation

I noticed with a lot of ES6 classes I created, the class itself and methods aren't always displaying the JSDoc comments on hover. I noticed that once I CTRL-SHIFT-F search the class and find the file and open it, VSCode then figures out those JSDoc comments are there and now if I hover in a file using the class or methods within the class it displays the documentation. This defeats the purpose of writing the JSDoc for easily accessing it from another file without searching. Could this be due to the fact the codebase is very large?

I expect to be able to hover over the class no matter where I am in the codebase and see the documentation. I noticed too that I can't even right click and go to definition until the file containing the documentation is open.